# How to make a UIElement width relative to the parent container (in this case, StackPanel)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, uielement

How to make a UIElement (in my case it's a `Line`) width relative to the parent container (in this case, StackPanel)? Relative means stretched and shrink based on the parent.

```
<UserControl x:Class="RevisiConverter.NumericNote"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Background="White">
<StackPanel Name="mainStack">
    <StackPanel Name="topStack">
        <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="20" Y2="0" Margin="0,2,0,2" Stroke="Black"/>
        <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="20" Y2="0" Margin="0,2,0,2" Stroke="Black"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Name="txbNote" Text="b5" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="15"/>
    <StackPanel Name="botStack">

    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

In above sample, `topStack` is already filled by 2x `Line` directly from the xaml, but, in reality, it's filled from the C# code (initial `Children` count of `topStack` is 0).

The size of the `UserControl` is relative to its `Children`, but will always have at least 1 children, which is `txbNote`, and `txbNote` will always at least have 1 character.

So, in short, I need the `Line` length, if exists, is always equal to `txbNote` width. While `txbNote` can be updated anytime.

How to achieve this, especially from the C# code-wise?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the code-behind binding looks like that:

```
var newLine = new Line();

// some newLine initializing

Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = topStack;
binding.Path = new System.Windows.PropertyPath("ActualWidth");
newLine.SetBinding(Line.X2Property, binding);

topStack.Children.Add(newLine);
```

Comment: Will it be the same as calling `newline.X2 = txbNote.ActualWidth` after each time `txbNote.Text` is changed?

Comment: I'm not sure about `txbNote.Text` property, but after `TextBlock.SizeChanged` event appeared - yes.

Answer (score 1):

It is important that you realise that in WPF, different container controls behave differently. There are `Panel` controls, such as a `Grid`, that can perform resizing actions on their children controls automatically and there are other `Panel` controls, such as a `StackPanel` that don't. It is a better idea to use the correct control for the job, rather than trying to make the wrong control do a job that it was never meant to do.

In your case, I'd suggest that you replace your `StackPanel`s with a `Grid`s and let them automatically fill the space for you. Please see the [`Grid` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for further information on this. You can also find out more about the various `Panel`s used in WPF in the [Panels Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Using `Grid` is not possible, since `Line` can be added anytime by the user. `Grid` is nice when the number of the element can't be changed. Am I right? Not quite sure though.

Comment: *`Line` can be added anytime by the user* is *not* a reason to not use a `Grid`... they can be added to a `Grid` in exactly the same way as a `StackPanel`, but suit yourself.

Comment: @Moses You might then also replace the Line by a Rectangle with `Height="1"` and `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` which would automatically stretch to the parent width.

Comment: @Clemens that's a great idea too!

Answer (score 0):

Bind `X2` to the `ActualWidth` of the TextBlock:

```
<Line ... X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=txbNote}" />
```